# A unusual inequality about function $\ln$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, inequality

These day,I met a unusual inequality when I solve a difficult problem, and proving the inequality means I have done the work!
Could you show me how to prove it or deny it? By the way, I believe that it's true!

> Prove that, for all $t > 0$,
> \begin{align*}
> &4\ln t\ln (t + 2) - \ln t\ln (t + 1) - 3\ln t\ln (t + 3)\\
>  + &4\ln (t + 1)\ln (t + 3) - 3\ln (t + 1)\ln (t + 2) - \ln (t + 2)\ln \left( {t + 3} \right)>0.
> \end{align*}

Let
$$f\left( t \right) = 4\ln t\ln \left( {t + 2} \right) - \ln t\ln \left( {t + 1} \right) - 3\ln t\ln \left( {t + 3} \right) + 4\ln \left( {t + 1} \right)\ln \left( {t + 3} \right) - 3\ln \left( {t + 1} \right)\ln \left( {t + 2} \right) - \ln \left( {t + 2} \right)\ln \left( {t + 3} \right),$$
We have
$$f'\left( t \right) = \frac{{2\left[ {{t^2}\ln t - 3{{\left( {t + 1} \right)}^2}\ln \left( {t + 1} \right) + 3{{\left( {t + 2} \right)}^2}\ln \left( {t + 2} \right) - {{\left( {t + 3} \right)}^2}\ln \left( {t + 3} \right)} \right]}}{{t\left( {t + 1} \right)\left( {t + 2} \right)\left( {t + 3} \right)}}.$$
Let
$$g\left( t \right) = {t^2}\ln t - 3{\left( {t + 1} \right)^2}\ln \left( {t + 1} \right) + 3{\left( {t + 2} \right)^2}\ln \left( {t + 2} \right) - {\left( {t + 3} \right)^2}\ln \left( {t + 3} \right),$$
we got
$$g'\left( t \right) = 2\left[ {t\ln t - 3\left( {t + 1} \right)\ln \left( {t + 1} \right) + 3\left( {t + 2} \right)\ln \left( {t + 2} \right) - \left( {t + 3} \right)\ln \left( {t + 3} \right)} \right].$$
And let
$$h\left( x \right) = t\ln t - 3\left( {t + 1} \right)\ln \left( {t + 1} \right) + 3\left( {t + 2} \right)\ln \left( {t + 2} \right) - \left( {t + 3} \right)\ln \left( {t + 3} \right),$$
we have
\begin{align*}
h'\left( x \right) &= \ln t - 3\ln \left( {t + 1} \right) + 3\ln \left( {t + 2} \right) - \ln \left( {t + 3} \right)\\
&= \ln \frac{{t{{\left( {t + 2} \right)}^3}}}{{{{\left( {t + 1} \right)}^3}\left( {t + 3} \right)}} = \ln \left[ {1 - \frac{{2t + 3}}{{{{\left( {t + 1} \right)}^3}\left( {t + 3} \right)}}} \right] < 0.
\end{align*}
However, it seems that there are no use!

Comment: Why?  (Where did this proposed inequality come from?)

Comment: By the way, for normal sized parentheses in MathJax (and $\LaTeX$), you don't need to bother with such complicated expressions as `\left( {t + 1} \right)`.  Just `(t + 1)` suffices to produce $(t + 1)$.

Comment: @SammyBlackThank you,but $1$ isn't the root

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that for $t> 0$,
$$4\ln t \ln (t + 2) + 4 \ln (t + 1) \ln (t + 3) > \ln t \ln ( t + 1) + 3\ln t \ln (t + 3) + 3\ln (t + 1) \ln (t + 2) $$

**Case $t> 1$**

Note that $\ln t, \ln (t+1)$ and $\ln (t+2), \ln(t+3)$ are similarly ordered, so by Rearrangement 
$$\ln t \ln(t+2)+\ln (t+1) \ln(t+3) > \ln t \ln(t+3) + \ln (t+1) \ln (t+2)$$

So it is enough to show that
$$\ln t \ln (t + 2) +  \ln (t + 1) \ln (t + 3) > \ln t \ln ( t + 1) $$
$$\iff \ln t(\ln (t + 2)-\ln(t+1)) + \ln(t+1)\ln (t + 3) > 0$$
which is obvious as $\ln$ is increasing.

**Case $0< t \le 1$**
We can write the inequality as
$$\ln (t + 1) \ln \frac{(t+3)^4}{(t+2)^3} > \ln t \ln \frac{(t+1)(t+3)^3}{(t+2)^4}$$
As the fractions in the arguments are $> 1$, the LHS is clearly positive while the RHS is negative from the $\ln t$ term.

Comment: It seems your first equation misses one term $\ln(t + 2)\ln (t + 3)$ on the RHS. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The desired inequality is written as
$$3ac - ab - b^2 - bc \ge 0$$
where
$a = \ln (t + 1) - \ln t, ~
b = \ln(t + 2) - \ln(t + 1)$ and
$c = \ln(t + 3) - \ln(t + 2)$.

Clearly, $a > b > c > 0$.

**Fact 1**: It holds that, for all $u \ge 0$,
$$\frac{2u}{2 + u} \le \ln(1 + u) \le \frac{u}{2}\cdot \frac{2 + u}{1 + u}.$$
(*Note*: See [bounds for logarithm](https://rgmia.org/papers/v7n2/pade.pdf). It is also easily proved by taking derivative.)

Using Fact 1, we have
$$c \ge \frac{2}{2t + 5}, \quad a \ge \frac{2}{2t + 1}, \quad b \le \frac{2t + 3}{2(t + 1)(t + 2)}. \tag{1}$$
(*Note*: For example, we have $a = \ln(1 + \frac{1}{t})$. Let $u = \frac{1}{t}$.)

Using (1) and $a > b > 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
 & 3ac - ab - b^2 - bc\\
 =\,& (3a - b) c - ab - b^2\\
 \ge\,& (3a - b)\cdot \frac{2}{2t + 5} - ab - b^2 \\
 =\,& \left(\frac{6}{2t + 5} - b\right)a - \frac{2b}{2t+5} - b^2 \\
 \ge\,& \left(\frac{6}{2t + 5} - \frac{2t + 3}{2(t + 1)(t + 2)}\right)a - \frac{2b}{2t+5} - b^2\\
 =\,& \frac{8t^2 + 20t + 9}{2(2t+5)(t+1)(t+2)} a - \frac{2b}{2t+5} - b^2\\
 \ge\,& \frac{8t^2 + 20t + 9}{2(2t+5)(t+1)(t+2)} \cdot \frac{2}{2t+1} - \frac{2}{2t+5}\cdot \frac{2t+3}{2(t+1)(t+2)} - \left(\frac{2t+3}{2(t+1)(t+2)}\right)^2\\
 =\,& \frac{3}{4(2t+5)(t+1)^2(t+2)^2(2t+1)}\\
 >\,& 0.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.

Try plugging in a large value for t such as $10^9$ (tried in R and sage)

Comment: [For $10^9$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4ln+%28t-3%2F2%29+ln+%28t%2B1%2F2%29+%2B+4+ln+%28t-1%2F2%29+ln+%28t%2B3%2F2%29+-3+ln+%28t-3%2F2%29+ln+%28t%2B3%2F2%29+-+3+ln+%28t-1%2F2%29+ln+%28t%2B1%2F2%29+-+ln+%28t-3%2F2%29+ln+%28t-1%2F2%29+-+ln+%28t%2B3%2F2%29+ln+%28t%2B1%2F2%29+at+t%3D10^9)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:  I made a typo, entering the function into the graphing software, leading to the following believable conjecture (based on the incorrect graph).**  I'll leave the answer up for posterity, but please don't upvote it.

Conjecture:

- $f(t) > 0$ for $0 < t < 1$,
- $f(t) < 0$ for $t > 1$,
- $f(1) = 0$, and $t = 1$ is the only root,
- $f'(t) < 0$ for all $t > 0$ ($f$ is always decreasing),
- $f''(t) > 0$ for all $t > 0$ ($f$ is always concave up).

[image: Incorrect graph.]

---

**Here's a better graph,** which suggests that the inequality in the question is correct.
[image: Correct graph.]

By the way, you can have a look at the graph and manipulate the zoom [*here*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uk4lbjlr1c).

Comment: Excuse me, I went to your link and I noticed that the first term was $4\log t\ln(t+2)$ instead of $4\ln t \ln(t+2)$. I believe desmos uses $\log:=\log_{10}$, because when I made the substitution $\log \mapsto \ln$ it the plot changed *considerably*.

Comment: Does this not just change the vertical stretch of the function? Through the change of base formula, one can turn $\log(\cdot)$ into $\ln(\cdot)$ with a factor of $\log(e)$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, you are entirely correct.  I'm not sure how the base $10$ logarithm snuck in there.

Comment: @LinusS.  That's true, but the typo only affected **one** of the logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is true. I test the expression from $t = 10^{10}+1$ to $t = 10^{10}+10000$ in Matlab. The min is about $-9.1\times 10^{-13}$. It may be due to the floating error. However I think the limit when $t$ tends to $\infty$ is 0 but it would not be constantly positive.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as hard as it seems (if we use Maple, of course :).

Let's rewrite our inequality:
$$4\ln(t)\ln(t+2)+4\ln(t+1)\ln(t+3) > \\\ln(t)\ln(t+1)+3\ln(t)\ln(t+3)+3\ln(t+1)\ln(t+2)+\ln(t+2)\ln(t+3)$$
Now we use $\ln(t+1)=\ln t+\ln(1+\frac1t)$ and denote $x=1/t$. LHS is
$$4\ln(t)\cdot\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+2x)\big)+4\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+x)\big)\cdot\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+3x)\big),$$
or
$$8\ln^2(t)+4\ln(t)\ln(1+2x)+4\ln(t)\ln(1+3x)+4\ln(1+x)\ln(t)+4\ln(1+x)\ln(1+3x).$$
RHS is
$$\ln(t)\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+x)\big)+3\ln(t)\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+3x)\big)+\\+3\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+x)\big)\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+2x)\big)+\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+2x)\big)\big(\ln(t)+\ln(1+3x)\big),$$
or
$$8\ln^2(t)+4\ln(1+x)\ln(t)+4\ln(t)\ln(1+3x)+4\ln(t)\ln(1+2x)+\\+3\ln(1+x)\ln(1+2x)+\ln(1+2x)\ln(1+3x).$$

We see thar $\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}>0$ is just
$$h(x) = 4\ln(1+x)\ln(1+3x)-3\ln(1+x)\ln(1+2x)-\ln(1+2x)\ln(1+3x)>0.$$

Now we will use that: if $f(0)=0$, $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$, then $f(x) > 0$ for $x>0$. Our goal is to show that $h(x) > 0$ for $x>0$ ($x=1/t>0$). Let's go.

$h(0)=0$, and
$$h'(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)}\times\\\times \left( \left ( 6\,{x}^{2}+6+12\,x \right) \ln  \left( 1+x \right) + \left( -
24\,x-24\,{x}^{2}-6 \right) \ln  \left( 1+2\,x \right) + \left( 2+12\,
x+18\,{x}^{2} \right) \ln  \left( 1+3\,x \right) \right)$$
or
$$h'(x) = \frac{2}{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)}\times\\\times \left(6\, \left( 1+x \right) ^{2}\ln  \left( 1+x \right) -6\, \left( 1+2\,x
 \right) ^{2}\ln  \left( 1+2\,x \right) +2\, \left( 1+3\,x \right) ^{2
}\ln  \left( 1+3\,x \right) \right) =\\= \frac{g(x)}{(1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)}.
$$
I want to show that $g(x)>0$. $g(0)=0$, and
$$g'(x)=\left( 1+x \right) \ln  \left( 1+x \right) -2\left( 1+2\,x \right) 
\ln  \left( 1+2\,x \right) + \left( 1+3\,x \right) \ln  \left( 1+3\,x
 \right) = h(x).
$$

Now you can guess about next step:) $h(0)=0$,
$$h'(x)=\ln  \left( 1+x \right) -4\,\ln  \left( 1+2\,x \right) +3\,\ln 
 \left( 1+3\,x \right)  = u(x)
$$

$u(0)=0$,
$$u'(x) = {\frac {2}{ \left( 1+x \right)  \left( 1+2\,x \right)  \left( 1+3\,
x \right) }} > 0.
$$

It's all.

Comment: @ Michael Galuza: How about the evaluation of the LHS of the inequality under consideration by $t = 2.64462229510112625406868003634 \cdot 10^8 $ with the accuracy $30$ digits which equals $-1.3\cdot10^{-26} $ up to Maple?

Comment: @user64494, I said one word to you, just one word: underflow

Comment: @user64494, do you really think that a result like $10^{-26}$ is correct and meaningful? Even if accuracy is 30 digits.

Comment: @ Michael Galuza : Why $\ln(1+2x)\ln[(1+x)^3(1+3x)] < \ln(1+2x)\ln[(1+x)^4]?$

Comment: @user64494, damn it, you're right. I hope, somebody make last step correctly.

Comment: @user64494, I edited post